# If I define $F(x)=\int f(x)\:dx$, is right to say that $F(u)=\int f(u)\:du$

Tags: calculus, notation, indefinite-integrals

I thought that the $dx$ sign can't be changed to $du$. For example, instead of $x=u$, If I had $x=2$, then I would have to evaluate $F(2)=\int f(2) \: d2 $, but this can't be right. It makes sense to define a function $F(x)=\int f(x)\:dx$ then say that $F(u)=\int f(u)\:du$?

Comment: The symbol $\int f(x)\,dx$ is ambiguous.  Better is $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt+C=\int_a^x f(u)\,du+C=\int_a^x f(v)\,dv+C$, etc.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html

Comment: You can, since $x$ (or $u$) in an indefinite integral is a dumb variable.

Comment: Ok, so i'm not allowed to say $x=2$? I'll do some research on this dummy variable.

Comment: If you write $F$ as in Mark's comment, you can set $x=2$

Comment: $dx$ is a notation linked to the variable $x$, but when $x=4$ $dx$ does not change, it's not a number. Unless if you define as Mark, precising on which domain you integrate and defining a function within it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let us make some clarifications over the symbol $\int f(x) dx$. In general, whith this, we are used to note a *whole family* of functions, not just one function - you can see the specific construction of this family [in the first part of this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581330/constant-of-integration-change/2581755#2581755). So, writing:
$$F(x)=\int f(x)dx$$
has no meaning, since the left hand side of this equation is a *function* and the right one is a *set of functions*. Even writing:
$$F(t)=\int f(x)dx$$
has no meaning, for the same reasons.

So, keeping in mind that the indefinite integral is a symbol for a set of functions - with a common property - what one could use is the symbol of the definite integral, as mentioned in the comments section by @Mark Viola. So, for instance, one can write:
$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$$
which is, if $f(x)\geq0$ over its doamin, the area under $f$ from $a$ to $x$ - or the opposite of this area, if $x<a$. Note that "inside" the integral we use a different variable than that we use at its limits. So, one can also write:
$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(u)du$$
Using the same variable "inside" and "outside" the integral would cause a large confusion as of with respect to what are we integrating.

You can also make both limits of integration be variable:
$$F(x)=\int_x^{x+1}f(t)dt$$
or, more generally, if $g,h$ are two "nice" functions - for instance, continuous - we can consider:
$$F(x)=\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)dt$$

Note, however, that the following has a meaning:
$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(x)dt$$
To interpret this, one can think as follows: $dt$ tells us with respect to which variable are we integrating. So, in our case, this variable is $t$ and, hence, everything that does not contain $t$ is considered to be a fixed number. So, for this case $f(x)$ is a plain number, and, we have:
$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(x)dt=f(x)\int_a^x1dt=f(x)(x-a)$$
So, this was a more "tricky" way to write the function $f(x)(x-a)$.

Finally, we can have even more complex cases, as the following:
$$F(x)=\int_a^xg(x-t)f(t)dt$$
but the discussion has already gone too far...

Comment: Can I say that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt = \int_a^x f(u)du $  ?

Comment: Oh, yes, in this case, the variable inside the interal can have any "name" as long as the change is applied to all the appearances of it inside the integral, with $dt$ included. Just avoid using the same name inside an outside the integral when this variable is also included in $dt$ symbol.

Comment: What about the indefinite integrals: $\int f(t)dt=\int f(u)du$  ?

Comment: I'm trying to prove a theorem, that states that if $\int f(t)dt$ is non elementary than $\int f^{-1}(t)dt$ is also non elementary. But in my proof I write $\int f^{-1}(t)dt$ in function of $\int f(u) du$. If I assume that $\int f(t)dt$ is non elementary than is also $\int f(u) du$ ? I putted this question in here, and the answers appears $F(x)=\int f(x)dx$ which you said don't make sense, so i'm not conviced of the proofs that I received.

Comment: Can you post a link of that question. The most possible scenario is that the answerer intented to write something like $$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$$, but just used indefinite integrals due to possible time restrictions.

Comment: Here is the orginal question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588305/proof-of-this-theorem-about-non-elementary-integrals  Here is the follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589588/prove-that-if-int-fx-dx-is-non-elementary-then-int-f-1x-dx-is-also

Comment: So, in these questions, $F(x)=\int f(x)dx$ is used with the notion "F(x)" is a function such that $F'(x)=f(x)$. As explained, this is in general wrong, but, mathematicians being the most lazy people in the world, makes many mistaken, however comfortable, pactices being used very often.

Comment: So in these questions, if the integral $\int f(u)du$ appears, I can call this integral $F(u)$? Even if i define first that $F(x)=\int f(x) dx$.

Comment: Yes, having always in mind that it is meant that this is a function that has as its derivative the function $f$.